# Responding to a deleted message does not notify the user?

Tags: bug, chat, ping

If you respond to a message in chat, which has either previously been deleted or is deleted as you're responding, the person that you're responding to does not get a notification to state they were pinged.

For example:

user 1 posts message id 1 stating `mmmmm cake`

user 2 clicks reply to message id 1 and posts message id 2 stating `yay cake`, but before posting the message, message id 1 is deleted

The following happens:

Message id 2 is posted, in response to message id 1, but neither the "responding to" arrow appears (which could be expected behaviour) nor the user who posted message id 1 gets notified (which I would still expect to happen, since you're still pinging that user)

Answer (score 3):

This is quite an edge case IMO.

I don't think that it would make sense to display the "responding to" icon because it would link to deleted content - it would be impossible to understand the context of the reply.

Regarding the ping to the first user, I don't think that should happen either. The content has been removed by the author (or moderator). The user that removed the content doesn't want that message to appear in the chat room so pinging the author about a reply would make no sense - "It's deleted content, no one* is supposed to be able to see it anyway!"

Lets take a look at the normal case of this scenario:

1. User1 posts a message
2. User2 responds to that message

   1. The response message does ping User1 and does include the "responding to" icon.
3. The original message by User1 is removed.
4. The response message looses it's "responding to" icon. Pings can't be taken back though :)

Examining the same behavior for a message that is deleted after a response has been sent, the behavior is identical.

** Not including mods/SE employees.*

Comment: My post is specifically about the ping, I wouldn't expect the "replying to" icon to be present either, since deleted messages don't show up in many places